# PopupMenu me manda error

Tags: flutter, vscode, botón, dart, aplicación-movil

Estoy tratando de hacer un botón desplegable para configuraciones, pero me manda error y no se por qué.

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  HomeState createState() => HomeState();
}

class HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: const Icon(Icons.qr_code_scanner_sharp),
        onPressed: () => _scan(),
      ),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Titulo'),
        actions: [
          PopupMenuButton<int>(
            itemBuilder: (context) => {
              PopupMenuItem(
                child: Text("Configuraciones"),
              )
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: _getDrawerItemWidget(_selectDrawerItem),
    );
  }
}
```

les agradeceria mucho que me ayudaran, no encuentro mucha informacion al respecto y la que encuentro no la entiendo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El `PopMenuButton` se alimenta de una `lista`, así que antes de agregar un `PopMenuItem` tienes que inicializar una `lista` y luego ir agregando los `PopMenuItem`, supongo que el error que te sale es porque no estas retornando nada, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
PopupMenuButton<int>(
      onSelected: (value) {
        if (value == 0) {
          print('configuraciones');
        }
      },
      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      elevation: 10,
      icon: const Icon(Icons.more_vert),
      color: Colors.white,
      itemBuilder: (context) {
        var list = <PopupMenuEntry<int>>[];
        list.add(const PopupMenuItem(
          value: 0,
          child: Text("Configuraciones"),
        ));
        return list;
      },
    )
```

Espero y mi respuesta te haya ayudado.

Comment: muchisimas gracias, si me funciono